# SQLite Database compare date with format "mmm dd yyyy hh:mm"

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, format, android-sqlite

I developed an Android Apps with SQLite database.My task is to compare today date with database date. Unfortunately, my date is "mmm dd yyyy hh:mm" and the data type is smalldatetime.

For example, how do I compare "Mar  9 2018  6:00AM" >= todayDate?

If cannot compare, can I change this datetime format "mmm dd yyyy hh:mm" to "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Thank you.

Comment: Convert your date string to 'Date' and then you can compare tody's date with that date, by simple maths.

Comment: Ya, u r correct. Thank for help.